# ClassCastException when trying to Add HeaderView to listView android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to add HeaderView to my EndlessListView

Here is the code

```
mainLayout is the parent of SwipeLayout in which ListView is placed
ViewGroup headerView = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.profile_header, (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), false);
        listView.addHeaderView(headerView, null, false);
        adapter = new  TrafficTweatsAdapter(this, tweatsList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I am getting this error

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams
            at android.widget.ListView.clearRecycledState(ListView.java:513)
            at android.widget.ListView.resetList(ListView.java:499)
            at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:442)
            at com.app.custom.EndlessListView.setAdapter(EndlessListView.java:45)
```

If i put null instead of bgLayout or return true, it gives me error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2269)
            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1769)
```

Comment: Can you share TrafficTweatsAdapter getView method code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting error cause you are inflating layout in wrong way. Let's take a look to [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate(int,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean)):

> public View inflate (int resource, ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot)
>
> root  Optional view to be the parent of the generated hierarchy (if attachToRoot is true), or else simply an object that provides a set of LayoutParams values for root of the returned hierarchy (if attachToRoot is false.)

So, you are specifying `RelativeLayout` as paretnt and `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` are taking from that layout. After that you are trying to add that view to `ListView` which useses `AbsListView.LayoutParams` layout params.

You should be able to add footer by inflating it with `ListView` specified as parent instead `mainLayout`

Comment: put `listVIew` instead of `(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout)`

Comment: i have placed listView inflate(R.layout.profile_header, listView, false); Now giving second NullPointerError FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2269)
            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1769)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672)

Comment: this probably mean that your adapter is not working properly. Show us your `getView` from adapter

Comment: @MuhammadUmar See similar Q at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27015544/android-widget-relativelayoutlayoutparams-cannot-be-cast-to-android-widget-absl 
 Check return value in getView()

Comment: @andrew the adapter is fine. It is working without headerView only difference is the ArrayList size is 0 (Not null), but it shouldn't give any problem, if i remove headerview it works just fine.